# Magento 2: Body scrolling when modal popup open on ios mobiles

Tags: magento2, mobile-device

while opening the modal popup body is scrolling on ios mobile devices. If I am applying position: fixed to body when popup opens it is not scrolling but the page is moving to top.
I just want the page to stay at the same position and it should not scroll. Please some one help on this. Thanks in the advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("input#showpopup").click(function () {
        
         $('body').addClass('modal-open-ios');
     });

     $(document).on('click', '.close', function () {
         
         $('body').removeClass('modal-open-ios');
     });
 });
```

Instead of **input#showpopup** and **.close** use can use your **class** and **id**.

**Add the below css:**

```
@supports (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) {

.modal-open-ios{
  overflow:hidden;
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Already i have tried this. It is not working for ios.

Comment: @Ramyasri answer is updated, try again..

Comment: thanks for the update. But no luck.